# Set attributes to the button but only works when I click it twice

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4

I have set some attributes to my button with some bootstrap elements, however when I click the button for the first time it didn't work. I need to click somewhere outside the button, and click the button again.

I had solve this by calling the function in onload and call it again in button, but now I'm in a situation that I can't do that anymore, so I was wondering is there any other ways to solve the problem?

Here is my code:
https://jsfiddle.net/a22177861/x381z0h6/6/

HTML:

```
 <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" onclick="PopOver(this,'Hi','Thank','You');">ClickMe！</button>
```

JS:

```
function PopOver(myObj, mgr, Adate, Vdate) {
        $(function () {
            myObj.setAttribute("data-container", "body");
            myObj.setAttribute("data-toggle", "popover");
            myObj.setAttribute("data-placement", "bottom");
            myObj.setAttribute("data-html", "true");
            myObj.setAttribute("data-trigger", "focus");
            myObj.setAttribute("title", "otherInfo");
            myObj.setAttribute('data-content', "MGR："+mgr+"<br />DATE1："+Adate+"<br />DATE2："+Vdate);

            $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover();
        });
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This `$('[data-toggle="popover"]').popover()` in your code initializes the popover, so you have to click twice to trigger it.

According to Bootstrap's [popover documentation](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/popovers/#methods):

> Reveals an element’s popover. Returns to the caller before the popover has actually been shown (i.e. before the shown.bs.popover event occurs). This is considered a “manual” triggering of the popover. Popovers whose both title and content are zero-length are never displayed.

You can use `.popover('show')` to manually trigger the popover.

It will be like this:

```js
function PopOver(myObj, mgr, Adate, Vdate) {
  myObj.setAttribute("data-container", "body");
  myObj.setAttribute("data-toggle", "popover");
  myObj.setAttribute("data-placement", "bottom");
  myObj.setAttribute("data-html", "true");
  myObj.setAttribute("data-trigger", "focus");
  myObj.setAttribute("title", "otherInfo");
  myObj.setAttribute('data-content', "MGR："+mgr+"<br />DATE1："+Adate+"<br />DATE2："+Vdate);

  $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('show');
}
```

Comment: My problem solved perfectly, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you write your code in a friendlier way. Some dead fields can be written directly in HTML

```
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-warning" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="bottom" data-html="true" title='otherInfo' onclick="PopOver(this,'Hi','Thank','You');">ClickMe！</button>

function PopOver(myObj, mgr, Adate, Vdate) {
  myObj.setAttribute('data-content', "MGR："+mgr+"<br />DATE1："+Adate+"<br />DATE2："+Vdate);
  $("[data-toggle='popover']").popover('show');
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your advise! I'll keep it in mind